# NUnit delayed constraint does not appear to work in Unity3d

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit

I'm attempting to check that a condition is met after n seconds. I thought I could use the `After` method to do this, but it's not working as I expected. Am I doing something wrong here?

The test seems to fail instantly, instead of after `delayInMilliseconds`.

Using Unity 2019.1.14f1, NUnit 3.5.0.0.

Example:

```
// fails
[Test]
public void TimePassed_Polling()
{
    Assert.That(
        () => Time.time > 5.0f,
        Is.True.After(delayInMilliseconds: 6000, pollingInterval: 100));
}

// passes
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator TimePassed_Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.0f);

    Assert.That(() => Time.time > 5.0f);
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything that looks wrong in what you've posted here. Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of NUnit?

Comment: @Chris I'll see if I can update NUnit. Not sure how easy that is with Unity. If code looks ok, I wonder if it's a problem with Unity's test runner.